# Generics и свой пример

Tags: java, generics

Просмотрел видео про Generic.

**Класс GenericMain**

```
public class GenericMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container<Integer> box = new Container<>(2);

        Container<String> box2 = new Container<>("2");

    }
}
```

**Класс Container**

```
public class Container<T> {

   private T object1;

   public Container(T object1) {
      this.object1 = object1;
   }

   public T getObject1() {
      return object1;
   }

   public void setObject1(T object1) {
      this.object1 = object1;
   }
}
```

Вопрос 1. Почему мы параметризовали класс `Container` причем буквой . Я проверил и заменил `<T>` на `<С>`, так же отрабатывает. Cтранно, что автор **умолчал**.

Вопрос 2. Если заменить `<T>` на `<Integer>`, то есть сделать вот так:

```
public class Container<Integer> {

   private Integer object1;

   public Container(Integer object1) {
      this.object1 = object1;
   }

   public Integer getObject1() {
      return object1;
   }

   public void setObject1(Integer object1) {
      this.object1 = object1;
   }
}
```

То тоже ничего не происходит, я думал подсветит компилятор красным вот этот участок кода:

```
Container<String> box2 = new Container<>("2");
```

Потому что мы параметризовали класс `Container` как тип `Integer`, а в этом участке кода , но в итоге всё нормально, получается зачем мы тогда указываем тип классу(<>) Container? В моём случае я туда писал всё что можно и отрабатывало как я увидел всё нормально и ничего не подсвечивало.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тут есть неправильное интерпретирование того, что написано в коде, нужно различать параметр типа (ориг. Type Parameter) и аргумент типа (ориг. Type Argument)

При создании экземпляра параметризованного класса мы задаем тип в качестве аргумента параметризации (в терминологии спецификации языка java - Type Argument):

```java
new Continer<Integer>();
```

При декларировании параметризованного класса вместо конкретных типов мы декларируем параметры (в терминологии спецификации - [Type Parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)):

```java
class Container<T> { }
```

В твоем примере написано так:

```java
class Container<Integer> { }
```

В последнем случае мы создаем параметр с именем `Integer`, что сбивает с толку потому что тут не нужно писать тип, тут нужно указать только имя параметра.
Для того чтоб не было путаницы есть [конвенция по именованию параметров](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), где рекомендуют использовать одиночные заглавные буквы:

- E - элемент (Element)
- N - число (Number)
- T - тип (Type)
- К - ключ (Key)
- V - значение (Value)

---

Если нужно что бы класс можно было параметризовать только числами и более специфичными типами, то нужно написать так:

```java
class Container<T extends Number> {
    private T value
    public Container(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    T getValue() { 
        return value; 
    }
}
```

Не соблюдая конвенцию по именованию параметров можно написать даже так:

```java
class Container<String extends Number> {
        private String value;
        public Container(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        String getValue() {
                return value;
        }
}
```

Ошибки этот код не вызовет, но **так делать не нужно**, потому что в данном случае `String` не будет интерпретироваться как тип `java.lang.String`, а будет использовано в качестве имени для параметра.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок не происходит, т.к. вы создаете два разных объекта. У первого объекта у `Container` тип `Integer`, у второго - `String`.

У разных объектов одного класса могут быть разные типы в дженериках.

Если бы вы вообще не указали тип в <>, то как раз была бы ошибка, т.к. компилятор ждет указания типа класса `Container`.

Зачем вообще нужно это указывать - вы в первый объект не сможете "вставить" ничего кроме `Integer`, т.е. `"2"` или `true` например,  а во второй - ничего кроме `String`.

Comment: Если бы вы вообще не указали тип в <>, то как раз была бы ошибка, т.к. компилятор ждет указания типа класса Container. - Он ругается потому что там ничего нет, а я думал будет ругаться на String, потому что в классе Container <Integer> Написано

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван в классе Container написано "любой тип". Класс - это всего лишь оболочка для объекта. Создание одного объекта никак не влияет на создание другого объекта.

Comment: Либо я вас не понимаю либо вы меня, поставлю вопрос по другому. Зачем нам Дженерики для классов? Например public class Container<Integer>

Comment: Дженерики нужны для более безопасной работы вашего кода. Для того, что бы не возникало ошибок при работе с кодом. Посмотрите тут, самый хороший пример - ArrayList. https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questsyntax.level07.lecture07